# Data Binding in code-behind refuses to work

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set a data binding in code-behind but it doesn't want to work.

When I do it in XAML like this:

```
<Label x:Name="lblSelectedItem" Margin="0,0,5,5" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="{Binding (Canvas.Left),ElementName=Ming}"></Label>
```

It works perfectly, but when I do it like this:

```
var X1Binding = new Binding("Canvas.Left") { ElementName="Ming"};
BindingOperations.SetBinding(lblSelectedItem, ContentProperty, X1Binding);
```

It doesn't get any value.

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parenthesis around `Canvas.Left` like this :

```
var X1Binding = new Binding("(Canvas.Left)") { ElementName = "Rect" };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(Lbl1, Label.ContentProperty, X1Binding);
```

Comment: Thank you very much :- )

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify several Binding property values.

```
var X1Binding = new Binding("Canvas.Left") { ElementName="Ming"};
//X1Binding.Source = ViewModel; // Well the canvas is not on the view model so default value is the datacontext of the view.
X1Binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
X1Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(lblSelectedItem, ContentProperty, X1Binding);
```

Comment: A `Content` binding is only one-way (from source to target). Specifying `BindingMode.TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` don't make any sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting binding and propertypath like below:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.ElementName = "Ming";
binding.Path = new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty);
lblSelectedItem.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);
```